# Add SSO AdministratorAccess User to CodeCommit Approval rule templates

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

I'm trying to create an approval rule template that allows only SSO users with AdministratorAccess policy can approve PR from develop branch to master branch but I always get "0 of 1 rules satisfied".

I configured these users via single sign-on/SAML.

Below is my approval rule, I tried with full ARN and syntax from AWS docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html#identifiers-arns) but It didn't work. What value should I use for Approval Pool?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you adding the role session name or a wildcard for the same? For your above role, did you try `arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess/RoleSessionNameOfApprover` or even the wildcard `arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess/*` after choosing fully qualified ARN? You can get the RoleSessionName value by doing `aws sts get-caller-identity` when you have assumed the role via SSO.  I know this might be the first thing you tried, but I don't have SSO set up in my personal account so I cannot confirm whether it works.

Comment: @KaustubhKhavnekar yes, you are right, I tried all formats for fully qualified ARN, AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess/*, AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess/account@domain, AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess/*@domain ..., and all others in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html#identifiers-arns but it always returns "0 of 1 rules satisfied" when I create PR.

Comment: Have you managed to fix that? I am facing the very same issue.

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out, I created the approval rules before committing to the repo first (I actually migrated from another repo). You should re-associate the approval rule after migrating/committing to the repo (by removing repo, saving rule, editing the rule and re-associate the repo and the branch).

Comment: You mean approval rules only work if you apply them before pushing code to the repo. Please correct me.

Comment: Nope. It's actually the other way around. Make sure that you committed to the repo at least once and to the branch you're creating the approval rule for. After that, create the rule. It worked with me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. It seems the approvers field is case sensitive. Validate if it is an exact match.

Answer (score -1):

The **Approver type** should be an IAM user name or *assumed* role.  You're setting a value for a regular role, but it needs to be set for an assumed role.

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-create-pull-request-approval-rule.html...

```
For assumed roles, the ARN format should be arn:aws:sts::AccountID:assumed-role/RoleName for roles
```

Try setting your ARN to the format above and see if that does the trick.

Comment: I tried all formats, you can see the reference identifiers URL in my question, and It didn't work. I expect the screenshots for worked configuration. I know how to search the docs.

Comment: Have you tried `AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess_*/*`  The last time I checked, SSO used a format like `AWSReservedSSO_PermissionSetName_RandomSuffix` to avoid name collision.Try setting your ARN to that format and see if that does the trick.

Comment: @FranxiHidro ^^

Comment: I removed the random string from my screenshot and your format did not work, I tried many formats (* prefix, suffix, *@domain, *my_username* ..., federated-user ...)

Comment: @FranxiHidro Out of curiosity, have you tried just `*` to see if it works when accepting any IAM identities?

Comment: * is not an ARN, it's a wrong format, you can use * as an IAM user but It won't work.